# Logitech G933 Headset volume control for just headset output

Tags: sound, keyboard, pulseaudio, logitech

I have 2 volume control knobs, my G15 keyboard has media keys, and my G933 headset has a volume wheel.

How do I lock in the volume knob on the headset to control the output of just the headset instead of affecting the main line output volume?

If I change my default output to my headset, the headset volume wheel will control the headset volume, but the so does the one on the keyboard.

If I change my default output to my line out, the headset volume wheel and the keyboard media keys control the volume of the line out.  While applications locked in to the headset, like Google Chrome using the G933 output/input, they are locked into their volume until I open and use the PAV (Pulse Audio Volume) Control.

Is there some way to even see how many volume knobs I have available? Can I isolate them to their respective devices if they have a dedicated output/input? For example, if the keyboard media keys have no audio output, it can control the default, but since my headset has its own output, it should control only its output.

`evtest` sees the different devices:

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  Dell Dell AC511 USB SoundBar
/dev/input/event3:  G15 Gaming Keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  G15 Gaming Keyboard
/dev/input/event5:  Logitech Logitech G933 Gaming Wireless Headset
/dev/input/event6:  Kingsis Peripherals ZOWIE Gaming mouse
/dev/input/event7:  G15 GamePanel LCD
/dev/input/event8:  HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
/dev/input/event9:  HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
/dev/input/event10: HDA Intel PCH Line
/dev/input/event11: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front
/dev/input/event12: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround
/dev/input/event13: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE
/dev/input/event14: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Side
/dev/input/event15: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
/dev/input/event16: HD Pro Webcam C920
/dev/input/event17: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event18: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event19: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event20: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/dev/input/event21: Eee PC WMI hotkeys
```

Is there a way to assign event4 to default audio, and event5 to control volume for just the headset? Maybe even assign event2 to the Dell AC511 USB sound output only?